Ado file return matrix
I'm trying to write an ado file that return my matrix
prog drop EM
program define EM, eclass
matrix P0 = (.9, 0.09,0.01 \ 0.1, 0.8, 0.1 \ 0.05, 0.15, 0.8)
return P0
end

EM

The error I got is invalid syntax. How to solve this? Thank you.

There are two errors that I can see.
Your program needs to be r-class to use return, not e-class.
You need to declare
return matrix P0 = P0

